# Perl (App::RecordStream) to add a field to a record that is a unique hash value (md5 or similar) for a subset of the other fields

Tags: json, perl, export-to-csv

I'm writing a *nix processing pipeline that starts with complex nested JSON and ends up with CSV. The last step in the pipeline is this:

```
 ... | recs-tocsv > my_csv_file.csv
```

Right now, the `...` above is flat newline delimited JSON that looks like this (all values are strings, not all keys are in all records, but every record has at least 1 `prefix_` key):

```
{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "prefix_key3" : "value3", "prefix_key4" : "value4"}
{"key1" : "value5", "key2" : "value6", "prefix_key3" : "value7", "prefix_key4" : "value8"}
```

I would like to add a new field to each record that is a unique hash value (md5 or similar) of the concatenated values of all keys that start with `prefix`. Output should look like this (still in compact form, but formatted with spaces here for clarity):

```
{"key1" : "value1", 
 "key2" : "value2", 
 "prefix_hash" : "0b129fd4ae0587f4e606c6a78ef977a1", 
 "prefix_key3" : "value3", 
 "prefix_key4" : "value4"}
{"key1" : "value5", 
 "key2" : "value6", 
 "prefix_hash" : "cf59a16edf48bcb0d0566ba3dc19843a",
 "prefix_key3" : "value7", 
 "prefix_key4" : "value8"}
```

Where `prefix_hash` is the md5sum (or equivalent) of "value3;value4", "value7;value8" etc.

I'm looking for an App::RecordStream command syntax that I can use in a `recs-xform` or `recs-eval` call. (A Perl snippet that takes `STDIN` and produces the right output on `STDOUT` would be fine too). I'm having difficulty working with multiple keys and chaining together multiple operations (get the values of all keys with `prefix`, join into one string, calculate md5sum, set md5sum as value for a new key). Anything that will work relatively quickly on the (Linux) command line that produces the right output would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the part about App::RecordStream for a second, I've tried to distill the crux of your problem, and if I've understood it correctly, the code below will do what you ask:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use JSON::XS;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    my $obj = decode_json($_);
    my $key = join(';', map { $obj->{$_} } grep { /^prefix/ } sort(keys(%$obj)));
    $obj->{prefix_hash} = md5_hex($key);

    print encode_json($obj), "\n";
}

__DATA__
{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "prefix_key3" : "value3", "prefix_key4" : "value4"}
{"key1" : "value5", "key2" : "value6", "prefix_key3" : "value7", "prefix_key4" : "value8"}
```

Output (pretty-printed for line wrapping):

```
{
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1",
    "prefix_key4": "value4",
    "prefix_hash": "55f506f7e49469e44f807f8b4f55a5ff",
    "prefix_key3": "value3"
}
{
    "key2": "value6",
    "key1": "value5",
    "prefix_key4": "value8",
    "prefix_hash": "fdb804ef84534068168f146bcbebf30e",
    "prefix_key3": "value7"
}
```

If you want to operate on `STDIN` or a list of files, change `while (<DATA>)` to `while (<>)` and remove the `__DATA__` block at the bottom.

Comment: Fantastic! That gave me enough to figure out what I was looking for as a `recs-annotate` command. Here's what ended up doing the trick:   `recs-annotate -k !prefix! -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex '{{prefix_hash}} = md5_hex(join(\";\", $r))'`

Comment: @user2997319 Great, glad I could help. Please see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Your answer is right, but my modification of it wasn't. Sorting and dereferencing is important! Here's the `recs-annotate` command that worked: `recs-annotate -k !^prefix! -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex '{{prefix_hash}} = md5_hex(join(";", sort @{$r->get_group_values("!^prefix!", 1)}))'`

Comment: Sorting is important to ensure that we're always hashing the same thing, since JSON objects are inherently unordered.